# Semiprime of the form $x^2 + 5 y^2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $a$ be a prime of the form $20 n + 3$ or $20 n + 7$
Let $b$ be a prime of the form $20 m + 3$ or $20 m + 7$.

Then the semiprime $ S = ab $ is always of the form

$ S = x^2 + 5 y^2 $.

For some integers $x,y$.

How to prove that ?

How does elementary number theory deal with this and how would analytic number theory deal with it ?

Does every proof use modular arithmetics ?

I wonder about analogue results too.
Such as a cubic case or a triple product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both primes are represented by $$ 2 u^2 + 2 uv + 3 v^2.  $$

Note: for a discriminant $\Delta,$ and a prime $p$ such that, first, $\Delta \neq 0 \pmod p,$ and then Legendre $$ (\Delta | p) = 1,  $$
a simple construction shows that there is a form of discriminant $\Delta$ that represents $p.$ Furthermore, the form can then be reduced, an easy thing for positive forms. Put together, for discriminant $-20,$ every prime with $(-20|p) = 1$ is represented by either $x^2 + 5 y^2$ or $2x^2 + 2xy+3y^2.$ There is just one form per genus: the primes $1,9 \pmod{20}$ are represented by $x^2 + 5 y^2,$  the primes $3,7 \pmod{20}$ are represented by $2x^2 +2xy+ 3 y^2.$

The representation of the product by $x^2 + 5 y^2$ is just Gauss composition.

in Cox, *Primes of the form $x^2 + n y^2,$* page 37 in the first edition, he gives a formula of Lagrange,

$$ (2x^2 + 2 xy+ 3 y^2)(2z^2 + 2zw + 3 w^2) = (2xz+xw+yz+3yw)^2 +5(xw-yz)^2  $$

Comment: Why are both primes of that form ? Is that z norm of a ring ?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590123/primes-of-the-form-2-x2-2-xy-3-y2

Comment: @mick, I gather you are not yet of university age. Along with the book by Cox, my favorite, and best for this material is Binary Quadratic Forms by Duncan A. Buell. Very helpful. Similar book, same title, by Buchmann and Vollmer. You probably should not be mentioning rings or norms if you do not know any algebraic number theory, people will answer assuming you already know many relevant things. This material goes back to Gauss, Lagrange, Legendre, and is really much easier than A.N.T.