# Primes of the form $ 2 x^2 + 2 xy + 3 y^2 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

> Why is every prime $3,7 (\bmod 20)$ of the form
>
> $$ 2 x^2 + 2 xy + 3 y^2 $$

I do not think that form is the norm of an abelian ring ?

How to prove this ?

Comment: There are not so many binary, reduced quadratic forms of discriminant $-20$.

Answer (score 2):

These are the norms of the non-principal ideals of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.
The ideals of prime norm in this ring have norms $2$, $5$ and $p$
with $p\equiv1,3,7,9\pmod{20}$. The principal ideals cannot have norms
$\equiv3,7$ and the non-principal ones cannot have norms $\equiv1,9$.

Comment: But why can the non-principles not have norm $1$ or $9$ ?